# How to upload image with Jasny's bootstrap imagepreview?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Jasny's Bootstrap. This is nice work!

I coudn't find solution for bootstrap upload image on page http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload

With bootstrap-fileupload.js, how can I upload image using Ajax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked this question to directly ARNOLD DANIELS who is owner of Jasny's Bootstrap.

Here is his answer:

> The whole point of the image preview is that the picture is show right
>   away, without the need to upload it to the server using AJAX. So it
>   stays just a regular form. You can post a form using AJAX
>   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ if needed.
>
> If you do want to upload the image using AJAX and don't want to use a
>   form, checkout
>   http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html

I used this sample with removing database releated lines and worked perfectly for me !

Comment: More info: http://www.jasny.net/articles/jasny-bootstrap-file-upload-with-existing-file/

Comment: "Bootstrap imagepreview" would have been a more appropriate name than "Bootstrap fileupload", since it doesn't help uploading anything….

Comment: @user1728278 You're right, therefor the plugin has been renamed to Bootstrap file input in v3.0.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels Great!

Comment: If you use the image uploader from 9lesson.
After jQuery version 1.7 .live is deprecated and is replaced by .on

Answer (score 3):

First you need to register the css and js files:

If you are using Yii Framework:

```
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->registerCSSFile("/css/fileupload.css");
$cs->registerScriptFile('/js/fileupload.js', CClientScript::POS_END);
```

Or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/fileupload.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fileupload.js"></script>
```

Then register the following script:

```
$cs->registerScript("imageUpload", "$('.fileupload').fileupload({uploadtype: 'image'});", CClientScript::POS_END) ;
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.fileupload').fileupload({uploadtype: 'image'});
</script>
```

Then add the following HTML code to your page:

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
  <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
  <div>
    <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" /></span>
    <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question on Google and just wanted to show I did it for anyone else interested (even if it's not the most elegant way)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fileinput-preview').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    var imgdata = ($('.fileinput-preview img').attr('src'));
    $.post( "upload.php", { imgdata: imgdata})
    .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
   })
})
```

This above piece of code detects when the file input preview has changed. It then finds the base64 data from the image tag, and uses jquery to post it to upload.php.

Upload.php simply takes the base64 image data and saves it as an image

```
$imgdata = $_POST['imgdata'];
$ifp = fopen("newimage.jpg", "wb"); 
$data = explode(',', $imgdata);
fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1])); 
fclose($ifp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The upload on jasny is more than a preview or client side upload management instead an ajax,  probably you need tp use other method or plugin, cause the jasny upload will send the preview path using the binary image displaying